# Core profile vs version string? Only getting GLSL 1.3/OGL 3.0 in mesa 10.0.1

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, intel

In theory, mesa 10.0.1 should support OpenGL 3.3 but currently I'm only getting 3.0 support.

glxinfo gives some confusing results...

```
[pdel@architect build]$ glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.0.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.0.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

(currently running Intel HD Graphics 4000)

Can anyone explain the difference between the "core profile version string" and the "version string" and why they're different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's right there in the release notes:

> [OpenGL 3.3 is ***only*** available if requested at context creation because compatibility contexts not supported.](http://www.mesa3d.org/relnotes/10.0.1.html)

It looks like [`glxinfo`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/demos/tree/src/xdemos/glxinfo.c) first tries to grab the highest supported core profile information and then drops back to non-core.

So you get two sets of versions, one for a core profile and another for a non-core profile.

If you want OpenGL 3.3 under Mesa you *must* create a core profile.