# How to tell which version of OpenGL my graphics card supports on Linux

Tags: linux, opengl

I am trying to figure out which version of OpenGL my graphics card and driver currently support.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47062/what-is-terminal-command-that-can-show-opengl-version) suggests running `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` which if fine, but here is (some) of that output:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 387.22                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 387.22
```

So it is hard to tell, is it 4.5 or 4.6?

Also the [official documentation from nVidia](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/126185/en-us) does not mention the answer either!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Core profile vs version string? Only getting GLSL 1.3/OGL 3.0 in mesa 10.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779242/core-profile-vs-version-string-only-getting-glsl-1-3-ogl-3-0-in-mesa-10-0-1)

Comment: Yep pretty much the same question however, I think that @derhass 's answer is significantly better.

Comment: Indeed it is. I learned some myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 387.22
> ```

That is the highest *legacy* version the implementation will support. There are several possibilities here:

1. This number will be <= 3.1 for OpenGL implementations not supporting modern OpenGL profiles (introduced in 3.2).
2. It might be the highest supported compatibility profile version if the implementation does support the compatibility profile and actually returns a compatiblity profile context when asked for  a legacy context
3. It might also be <= 3.1 even on implementations that do support GL >= 3.2 in a compatibility profile, but chose to not expose it when asked for a legacy context.

The nvidia proprietary driver falls in category 2.

For the core profile, there is simply no way to ask the implementation what it can support, as described in 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510889/how-can-i-know-which-opengl-version-is-supported-by-my-system/46511741#46511741):

> ```
> OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 387.22
> ```

That glxinfo output does *not* mean that your driver can't do 4.6 core. (It actually can). It just means that the glxinfo aren't aware of the presence of GL 4.6 right now, only only check for up to 4.5.

[The source code for glxinfo](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/demos/tree/src/xdemos/glxinfo.c?id=22bc355f1b324b6ea07e063b5f20be757ea7a8e5#n267)  will reveal the following logic:

```
   if (coreProfile) {
      /* Try to create a core profile, starting with the newest version of
       * GL that we're aware of.  If we don't specify the version
       */
      int i;
      for (i = 0; gl_versions[i].major > 0; i++) {
          /* don't bother below GL 3.0 */
          if (gl_versions[i].major == 3 &&
              gl_versions[i].minor == 0)
             return 0;
         ctx = create_context_flags(dpy, config,
                                    gl_versions[i].major,
                                    gl_versions[i].minor,
                                    0x0,
                                    GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
                                    direct);
         if (ctx)
            return ctx;
      }
      /* couldn't get core profile context */
      return 0;
   }
```

so it just iterates through an array `gl_versions` and checks if a context with that version can be created.

And OpenGL 4.6 was added to that array [in this commit](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/demos/commit/?id=22bc355f1b324b6ea07e063b5f20be757ea7a8e5) on October 11, 2017:

```
diff --git a/src/xdemos/glinfo_common.h b/src/xdemos/glinfo_common.h
index 0024f85..4d07f66 100644
--- a/src/xdemos/glinfo_common.h
+++ b/src/xdemos/glinfo_common.h
@@ -86,6 +86,7 @@ struct options

 /** list of known OpenGL versions */
 static const struct { int major, minor; } gl_versions[] = {
+   {4, 6},
    {4, 5},
    {4, 4},
    {4, 3},
```

So if you use a `glxinfo` which was compiled on a source code version before Oct 11 (which means basically every distro version right now), it simply will not show 4.6, even if your driver can do it.

> So it is hard to tell, is it 4.5 or 4.6?

It is 4.6 for both compatibility and core profile. But I only know that because I know that driver.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer but would you mind simplifying it a bit.  You use the terms `compatibility` `core` and (a new one to me) "`legacy`". 

`glxinfo` does print out `OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 387.22` so it seems like, why is it aware of 4.6.for the legacy profile, but not the core profile?

Comment: There is no _legacy_ profile. A used the term _legacy_ to refer to versions of OpenGL before the profiles were introduced. Since a compatibility profile is still compatible to applications using a legacy GL context (hence the name), a GL implementation might return a compatibility profile context of some higher version when a legacy context is requested, but there is no requirement to do so.

Comment: As far as your driver goes: it is capable of 4.6 compatibility profile (and will also offer that legacy to applications not asking for any profile), and it is also capable of 4.6 core profile, though your version of `glxinfo` is not capable to detect that in a reliable way.